# jQuery Google Maps implementation including route generation

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Does anyone know a jQuery implementation for Google Maps with which you can also generate the route?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to wrap the Google Maps API with jQuery. They can both live quite happily next to each other in one JavaScript application / file. And to be honest, how would you do this anyway? jQuery serves a different purpose than wrapping everything JavaScript'ish.

There are some good demos and tutorials for directions (I think that's what you mean with routes) in the [official API docs](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Directions). A small example can be found [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple.html). View the source of the page so see the code. It's quite easy to follow.

Comment: Thanx, it's clear to me now, from your answer and some other resources I've found, that there is not very much advantage in using jQuery for this.